# Android Crashes while upgrading the Picasso Library

Tags: android, picasso, okhttp

I'm trying to upgrade Picasso Library on my Android app from version `2.5.2` to the latest version of `2.71828`.

I'm using below versions of other concerning libraries.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.2'
implementation 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0' 
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
```

App crashes when I'm trying to launch, with the following Error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method readUtf8LineStrict(J)Ljava/lang/String; in class Lokio/BufferedSource; or its super classes (declaration of 'okio.BufferedSource' appears in /data/app/com.app.dev-64CjLuqx-zjNoiTFWtBRvA==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
```

Please advise me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: show me your whole build.gradle file of app

Comment: This looks more like class missing from okhttp

Comment: upgrade your retrofit and okhttp versions with latest.

Comment: In picasso library there are many changes when you upgrade to 2.71828 compared to previous versions, i faced some issue regarding the method with(context) in latest version

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after changing the version

After replacing
Picasso.with(context)...

by
Picasso.get()...

I did a clean of the project and it worked back

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me. Maybe you're trying to import Picasso as the official documentation indicates:

**Gradle**

> implementation 'com.squareup.picasso**3**:picasso:2.71828'

Take off the number three and try this way:

> implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

You most also change:

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
     .load(imgurl)
     .into(imageV);
```

To:

```
Picasso.get()
         .load(imgurl)
         .into(imageV);
```

Comment: This is my statement, implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'